# Logical error in ternary operator

Tags: php, boolean, ternary-operator

Can somebody explain me why that ternary operetor return the second option instead of the first ?

This is the code :

```
$token_sid =
    ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS &&
     !empty($config['form_token_sid_guests'])) ? $user->session_id : '';
```

And here are the values for my actual testing

```
$user->data['user_id'] = 36412
ANONYMOUS = 1
$config['form_token_sid_guests'] = 0
$user->session_id = 4c148b664b7284ecb776c0a932ddf008

$token_sid = ''
```

Any idea why that return the empty value instead of the user session id ?

Comment: You should consider using `if`/`else` instead of the ternary operator when the code is even a bit complex, to keep it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user->data['user_id'] = 36412
```

is not equal to

```
ANONYMOUS = 1
```

(36412 != 1)
So the first "AND"-Condition failes and your else-"Block" will be evaluated.